# How to create a list style with roman numerals in python using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

How to create a list style with roman numerals in python using python-docx?

I'm trying to create a number list style like this:

```
I. List item 1
II. List item 2
III. List item 3
IV. List item 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a code that generates your roman numerals and store in a list variable. With the list item use the `zip` function together with the list roman variable.

Comment: Do you mean adding numbers as a part of list item?  Generating literals like `'I. Item 1'`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: python-docx does not natively support roman numeral numbering because that's a custom numbering format. So the solution to generate your word document from a blank word document that has that style of numbering already created and then access that custom number style in your python code.